# Make JSlider move constantly

Tags: java, swing, jslider

I have this piece of code:

```
Timer timer;
ActionListener listener;
listener = new ActionListener() {
    int counter = 0;

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        counter++;
        jSlider1.setValue(counter);
        jSlider2.setValue(counter);
        jSlider3.setValue(counter);
        jSlider4.setValue(counter);
        jSlider5.setValue(counter);
        jSlider6.setValue(counter);
        jSlider7.setValue(counter);
        jSlider8.setValue(counter);
        jSlider9.setValue(counter);
        jSlider10.setValue(counter);
    }
};
timer = new Timer(50, listener);
timer.start();
```

The `JSLider` moves automatically.

How to make the slider so that when it reaches the end, it goes back to the beginning?

Comment: You want to reset the `counter` or you want to reverse it?

Comment: reverse the counter

Comment: basically the knob of the jslider would never stop

Comment: 1) ***Why?*** It sounds like you're trying to reinvent an indeterminate  `JProgressBar`. 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Can i make the slider move with Threads?  @MadProgrammer

Comment: @chicoo Yes and no.  Swing is NOT thread safe, so you shouldn't update the UI from outside the context of the Event Dispatching Thread. For that, you should be using a `SwingWorer`

Answer (score 1):

> reverse the counter

So, you need some value which dictates the amount to add/subtract from the `counter` on each `tick`.  You probably also need to know the min/max range the `counter` can travel through.

To this end, a simple `delta` value, which gets added to the `counter` and which can be inverted (+/-) when the `counter` reaches either end of the available range.

Maybe something like...

```
listener = new ActionListener() {
    int counter = 0;
    int delta = 1;

    int min = 0;
    int max = 100;

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        counter += delta;
        if (counter < min || counter > max) {
            delta *= -1;
        }
        counter = Math.min(max, Math.max(min, counter));

        jSlider1.setValue(counter);
        jSlider2.setValue(counter);
        jSlider3.setValue(counter);
        jSlider4.setValue(counter);
        jSlider5.setValue(counter);
        jSlider6.setValue(counter);
        jSlider7.setValue(counter);
        jSlider8.setValue(counter);
        jSlider9.setValue(counter);
        jSlider10.setValue(counter);
    }

};
```